# Passing multiple tables to stored procedure with multiple table-valued parameters problem

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to pass DataTables to a stored procedure that accepts multiple table-valued parameters. The problem is, it seems that all the parameters are being passed to the first one so I am getting errors like this:

> Trying to pass a table-valued
>   parameter with 13 column(s) where the
>   corresponding user-defined table type
>   requires 17 column(s).

Here's my code..

Stored Procedure header:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
@Parm1 Temp1TableType READONLY,
@Parm2 Temp2TableType READONLY,
@Parm3 Temp3TableType READONLY,
@Parm4 Temp4TableType READONLY,
@Parm5 Temp5TableType READONLY
```

@Parm1 has 17 columns, @Parm2 13 columns, @Parm3 3 columns, @Parm4 11 columns and @Parm5 has 8 columns.

C# code (I use Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks)

```
DataTable dtTable1 = dsSource.Tables[0];
DataTable dtTable2 = dsSource.Tables[1];
DataTable dtTable3 = dsSource.Tables[2];
DataTable dtTable4 = dsSource.Tables[3];
DataTable dtTable5 = dsSource.Tables[4];

SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Parm1", dtTable1);
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Parm2", dtTable2);
SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@Parm3", dtTable3);
SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@Parm4", dtTable4);
SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter("@Parm5", dtTable5);

param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param5.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

SqlParameter[] parms = new SqlParameter[5];
parms[0] = param1;
parms[1] = param2;
parms[2] = param3;
parms[3] = param4;
parms[4] = param5;

returnVal = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(CfgKeys.ConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "TestProc", parms);
```

Today I tried using SqlClient instead of Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks but I still got the same error.

```
SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CfgKeys.ConnString);
conn.Open();
using (conn) {
   SqlCommand cmdTestDataToServer= new SqlCommand("TestProc", conn);
   cmdTestDataToServer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Parm1", dtTable1);
   SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Parm2", dtTable2);
   SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@Parm3", dtTable3);
   SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@Parm4", dtTable4);
   SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter("@Parm5", dtTable5);

   param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   param3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   param4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   param5.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

   cmdTestDataToServer.Parameters.Add(param1);
   cmdTestDataToServer.Parameters.Add(param2);
   cmdTestDataToServer.Parameters.Add(param3);
   cmdTestDataToServer.Parameters.Add(param4);
   cmdTestDataToServer.Parameters.Add(param5);

   returnVal = cmdTestDataToServer.ExecuteScalar();
}

conn.Close();
```

When I run this, it seems that all the parameters are being passed to @Param1 hence the error I mentioned earlier. It works when I manually run the procedure in TSQL, so the error is on my code. Can anyone spot where I went wrong?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.. Forgot to mention that DataTable data is sent through a web service, so it was using the DataSet method GetXml. The problem was that the GetXml method does not include NULL columns hence the missing columns.

Thanks guys!